# Problem with EPS/Chemdraw-embedded picture missing

Tags: eps, epstopdf

I have a problem with Chemdraw and including a figure I created in Chemdraw (https://www.file-upload.net/download-14217531/test.cdx.html
), which additionally contains a embedded png file. The chemdraw file was converted to eps and included into the Latex document via `includegraphics` However, the place of the embedded figure is blank in the the converted pdf file (https://www.file-upload.net/download-14217532/test-eps-converted-to.pdf.html
). It just shows the molecules created via chemdraw. I printed the chemdraw file as a pdf to show how it should look like (see https://www.file-upload.net/download-14217535/test.pdf.html).

Is there any possibility to solve this issue?

I found out that saving the original chemdraw file as pdf file and converting it to a eps file works, so the problem has probably something to do with the eps file created via chemdraw? I would like to avoid saving it as a pdf first, because then I have to trim the file each time.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 



\begin{document} 

\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{test.eps}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First advice: remove the extension from `\includegraphics` path, e.g. `\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{test}`. Let the compiler do its job.

Comment: Three additional questions: 1) Why do you need EPS graphics instead of PDF? 2) Which *TeX compiler did you use? 3) Which *TeX distribution you have installed? Please edit the original post with such information.